# psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: database "news" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, vagrant

Trying to set up a connection to my postgres sql database to run queries via python code.

I am on a MAC (mojave 10.14.6) and am trying to connect to my virtal postgres database via a python script. I can access the databases via terminal window but when I try to connect using psycopg2 I get psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "students" does not exist.

I have checked I only have one instance of postgres, I have checked the port being used and put that in the parameters.

Postgres version is 11.5
Python version is python 3.7.4
I have checked the location of psql /usr/local/bin/psql
I have checked the location of postgres /usr/local/bin/postgres

Nothing recommended in any other post seems to work.

```
import psycopg2

#DBNAME = 'students'

def connect():

    print('Trying to connect to server ...')
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'students')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('select * from students')


    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(results)

    cur.close
    conn.close

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()

---------------------------------------------------------------------

Below works when I connect to the postgres database
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
import psycopg2

def connect():

    print('Trying to connect to server ...')

    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'postgres')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    print('PostgreSQL database version:')
    cur.execute('select version()')
    db_version = cur.fetchone()
    print(db_version)


    cur.close
    conn.close

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()

result:

RESTART: /Users/Karen/Documents/Backup/Karens_Documents/Web_Development/web_dev_nano/course-ud303/SQL/fullstack-nanodegree-vm-master/vagrant/db_test.py 
Trying to connect to server ...
PostgreSQL database version:
('PostgreSQL 11.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4), 64-bit',)

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Karen/Documents/Backup/Karens_Documents/Web_Development/web_dev_nano/course-ud303/SQL/fullstack-nanodegree-vm-master/vagrant/db_test.py", line 28, in <module>
    connect()
  File "/Users/Karen/Documents/Backup/Karens_Documents/Web_Development/web_dev_nano/course-ud303/SQL/fullstack-nanodegree-vm-master/vagrant/db_test.py", line 9, in connect
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = DBNAME)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "students" does not exist
```

Comment: Are you really sure your database ```students``` does exist? What is the command you use to connect to the database in the terminal?

Comment: psql students vagrant

Comment: Okay, this looks good I guess

Comment: I have multiple databases aside from students. I can access them all as above but not using psycopg2.connect

Comment: can you list databases once in the 2nd version of your code (once your login) - how do you run the script ? do you run with vagrant user too as you do when running from the CLI, it can be user related issue

Comment: As @FrédéricHenri pointed out, the problem is for sure user related. Use this line of code  `conn = psycopg2.connect(user='username', dbname = 'students')`, and the issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm sorry to say it did not work. When I do a psql -l I seem my databases with their name 'students' and the Owner 'vagrant'. The error I get now is: psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist. On the off chance I also tried user='vagrant' but that resulted in the same error.